# textfile for Windows

Tags: windows, monitoring, metrics, prometheus

I need to export some custom metrics generated by a script under Windows.

Under Linux, I am already doing it, based on Robust Perception / Brian Brazil article :

> The [node exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) includes many metrics out of the box, it can't possibly cover all use cases though. That's where the textfile collector comes in, allowing you to extend machine instrumentation for your use case. [read more](https://www.robustperception.io/monitoring-directory-sizes-with-the-textfile-collector)

Unfortunately [wmi-exporter](https://github.com/martinlindhe/wmi_exporter) doesn't seem to have similar feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WMI Exporter has a `textfile` collector [since version 0.3.0](https://github.com/martinlindhe/wmi_exporter/commit/cf792394f37d046563ecdb9616b8bede73695bc6).

- The collector is enabled by default.
- The default directory for metrics is `C:\Program Files\wmi_exporter\textfile_inputs"`, but it can be overridden by the command line option `--collector.textfile.directory`.